# PowerShell implicit remoting - scriptblock

Tags: powershell, scriptblock

I am attempting to use [implicit remoting](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff720181.aspx). We have a jump server in a different data center. I want to run `Invoke-Command` implicitly on that jump server to be able to run commands on other servers it can access. I am able to export `Invoke-Command`, and import the module with a prefix. The problem I am running into is that it says it cannot convert a string to a scriptblock.

Here is an example:

```
Invoke-xxxCommand -ComputerName 'whatever-server' -ScriptBlock {
    Write-Host $env:COMPUTERNAME
}
```

I understand I can just use a PSSession to connect to the jump server. I am curious why this does not work.

Here is the error:

> Cannot bind parameter 'ScriptBlock'. Cannot convert the "Write-Host $env:COMPUTERNAME" value of type "System.String" to type "System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock".

Comment: How do you run a command "implicitly"? What's `Invoke-xxxCommand`, something custom you cooked up? Did you perform spooky black magic on `Invoke-Command` itself and are you now expecting that to work somehow? Judging by the message, *something* is failing with remoting that causes the scripblock to be forwarded as its string representation (which does not roundtrip), but I'm unclear on how this situation came to be.

Comment: Note that if you're somehow trying to get double-hop remoting to work (that is, from machine A you go to machine B which then executes commands on machine C), you have to get quite a bit more tricky than this. When you remote from A to B, B can execute commands under your identity locally, but it cannot, by default, forward it to machine C. There are solutions to this, but that's best left to other questions.

Comment: @JeroenMostert _How do you run a command "implicitly"?_ Here's [a guide on implicit remoting](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff720181.aspx)

Comment: I believe that this is because everything gets deserialized in the pipe between your session and the remote session. Try using `Invoke-Expression` instead, and see if that works better for you.

Comment: Possible related to the fact, that `ScriptBlock`s deserialized as strings.

Comment: To add to @PetSerAl's comment: see https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/4218

Comment: @JeroenMostert - yes, I have the double hop issue taken care of.

Comment: @PetSerAl - I agree that is the problem. Just not sure how to resolve.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician - good idea. I am at home now, but will try again when I am back at work. Thanks!!!

Comment: @BenH - yes, that is exactly what implicit remoting is. Thank you for answering that!

Comment: Not sure why this got downvoted...

Comment: @mklement0 - yeah, that seems to be dead on. Thanks!

Comment: @TheMadTechnician - still does not work, even when using Invoke-Expression. Maybe this just cannot be done this way.

Comment: If you dig deeper into the powershell remoting, you will notice that it creates a proxy text based implementation of the module's cmdlets. In essense, it is probing for the cmdlet's contracts, renders to its best the sections of the cmdlet with the only difference being the implementation. Some parameter types cannot be used in this context and you will notice that the type of the `ScriptBlock` has been altered. Try to first `ToString` the script block and then use it as value to the proxy cmdlet.